# How to create a sample up with the same distribution i R

Tags: r

Is it possible in r to select a sample from a large file based on the distribution of a smaller file?  For instance if I have a customer database with a certain age distribution and want to compare it to the nation population with the same age distribution. Say the sample has 2% of the customers in age 23 and 3% with age 24 but for the whole nation we have a totally different distribution. So basically I want to expand the sample with the same distribution.

Could this be done with more than one variable, say age and zip code?

Comment: Try this: `?sample`

Comment: I don´t  see what to do. I have looked at examples where probabilities has been used for sampling but I don´t understand how to use the small data frame with the age and probability variables to apply to the larger data frame.

Comment: Let's have an example...